# Open new window using html button and script

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have create simple leave application system. this system would receive staff leave application, then their head of department will approve the leave application. after that, human resource department can view monthly leave which is can list all staff leave on selected month.

my problem occur on this part. when HR view the monthly leave, then HR want to view leave details by clicking button (View Details) as picture that i have created, the system will show the last details only although i click on 1st row.

[HR interface when view monthly leave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd0h3.jpg)

here my code...

```
                <tr><td> <?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td><td> <?php echo $row['staffname']; ?></td><td> <?php echo $row['noapply']; ?></td>
                <td><button onclick="myFunction()">View Details</button></td></tr>
                <script>
                function myFunction() {
                window.open("hrviewdatedetails.php?ID=<?php echo $row['LeaveID']; ?>", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=100, width=800, height=500");
                }
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass levae Id as argument in myFunction(LevId). and write the javascript code at the bottom of the page.

your code should look like this.

```
<tr><td> <?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td><td> <?php echo $row['staffname']; ?></td><td> <?php echo $row['noapply']; ?></td>
    <td><button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $row['LeaveID']; ?>)">View Details</button></td></tr>

</tr>

<script>
    function myFunction(levID) {
        window.open("hrviewdatedetails.php?ID="+levID, "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=100, width=800, height=500");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnext").click(function () {                    
                    window.open("HTMLPage.htm", "PopupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no");
                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass id in function . try this

```
            <td><button onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>')">View Details</button></td></tr>
            <script>
            function myFunction(id) {
            window.open("hrviewdatedetails.php?ID="+id, "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=100, width=800, height=500");
            }
            </script>
```